# PHP update json from received input and write back to same file

Tags: php, json

I have a json file stored on server & it looks like below:

```
{
    "support_link":"#",
    "support_link_2":"#",
    "packs":[
        {
            "identifier":1,
            "viewCount":0,
            "downloadCount":0
        },
        {
            "identifier":2,
            "viewCount":0,
            "downloadCount":0
        }
    ]
}
```

By using PHP, I want to update the viewCount & downloadCount of some of the arrays inside packs.
But the thing is the data is received via a `POST` method to the server which contains another json with info. of which identifier to update & what param to update, & I am not able to update the existing file & save it back.

Received Json format:

```
{
    "impressions": [
        {
            "identifier": "1",
            "impressionCount": 2
        },
        {
            "identifier": "100",
            "impressionCount": 2
        },
        {
            "identifier": "1000",
            "impressionCount": 2000
        }
    ],
    "downloads": [
        {
            "identifier": "1",
            "downloadCount": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

What I've tried to do so far:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
if ($json != '') {
    $properJsonFormatted = json_decode($json, true);
    $impressions = $properJsonFormatted['impressions'];
    $downloads = $properJsonFormatted['downloads'];
    
    $testConfig = 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if ($json != '') {
        $properJsonFormatted = json_decode($json, true);
        $impressions = $properJsonFormatted['impressions'];
        $downloads = $properJsonFormatted['downloads'];
    
        $testConfig = json_decode(file_get_contents("test_config.json"),true);
        $packs = $testConfig['packs'];
    
    
        foreach ($packs as &$pack) {
            $packIdentifier = $pack['identifier'];
            
            foreach ($impressions as $impression) {
                $impressionIdentifier = $impression['identifier'];
                if ($packIdentifier == $impressionIdentifier) {
                    $pack['viewCount'] += $impression['impressionCount'];
                    $newCount = $pack['viewCount'];
                    
                    print("Id: $packIdentifier,  ViewCount: $newCount\n");
                }
            }
        }
        
        put_file_contents("test_config.json" , $testConfig);
        // print_r($testConfig);
        // Save back the updated test_config.json
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for each `$pack` you loop through the `$impressions` looking for a matching `identifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Seem to have misinterpreted the question. The actual problem seems to be much simpler.

Change this:

```
put_file_contents("test_config.json" , $testConfig);
```

To this:

```
file_put_contents('test_config.json', json_encode($testConfig));
```

Also change this:

```
$packs = $testConfig['packs'];
```

To this:

```
$packs = &$testConfig['packs'];
```

As it seems you forgot to assign that by reference, while you correctly did that in the foreach.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I do not mean to add the objects received from input, what I want is, get the impressions array -> get identifier, if they both match -> increment the value of `viewCount` by adding `impressionCount`, same goes for downloadCount, However I am able to do that but the final `testConfig` when saved, does not have the updated data

Comment: I see. Your question and code wasn't clear on that (`$pack['viewCount'] = 1900;` ??). From my answer it's not hard to get from 'overwrite' to 'add'. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Sorry for that, that was just a placeholder, I updated how I tried with the code, the value seems to be updated now, but new values are not saved to the file back.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to always post the actual code you're struggling with ;). But it's ok, I think I can help you anyway. See my revised answer for a solution to what I think was going on.

Comment: Thanks again, I see that the test_config is indeed saved to the file :D, can say that for sure because the indentation goes away, but the changes are not reflected in the file, the values are still 0.

Comment: Haha. We'll get there. I spotted something else and updated my answer.